# Trilateration in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas

Does another word in Spanish for **"[Trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration)"** exist? RAE does not register the word "**Trilateración**". What is the real translation to in Spanish for "**Trilateration**"

> In geometry, **trilateration** is the process of determining absolute or relative locations of points by measurement of distances, using the geometry of circles, spheres or triangles.

Comment: Wikipedia https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateraci%C3%B3n suggests Trilateración but does not offer a verbal option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Trilateración` debería ser el término correcto, aunque no aparezca en el diccionario de la RAE. Una simpe búsqueda en Google revela que el término es usado en diversos documentos, manuales o ensayos relacionados con geometría, topografía y geofísica. Sirven de ejemplo los siguientes enlaces

- [Introducción al GPS Capítulo 3: Cómo funciona el GPS (**trilateración**)](http://www.mailxmail.com/curso-introduccion-gps/como-funciona-gps-trilateracion)
- [Qué es la trilateración satelital](https://www.youbioit.com/es/article/15626/que-es-la-trilateracion-satelital&size=_original)
- [Trilateración topográfica](https://html.rincondelvago.com/trilateracion-topografica.html)
- [Triangulación y Trilateración](http://ocw.upm.es/ingenieria-cartografica-geodesica-y-fotogrametria/topografia-ii/contenidos/Mis_documentos/Tema-9-Triangulacion-y-Trilateracion/Teoria_Triang_Tema_9.pdf) (ingeniería cartográfica geodésica y fotogrametría)
- [Trilateración](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiw5IP94ubXAhWpYd8KHVnOCisQFghpMAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcatedras.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar%2Fgeofisica%2Freferenciacion-en-geofisica%2Fteoria%2Finstrumental-y-tecnicas-topograficas%2Ftrilateracion&usg=AOvVaw1g84lTdODsrZuW6VgS9BG7) (Facultade de Ciencias Astronómicas y Geofísicas)

El término "[triangulación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulaci%C3%B3n)" (que sí [está en el DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=abXseap)) no recoge por completo el significado de la "trilateración" (el primer método usa los triángulos, mientras que la trilateración usa también círculos y esferas). La trilateración es un tipo de triangulación.

Parece razonable pensar que la comunidad científica de habla hispana entiende y usa sin ningún problema el termino `trilateración` como traducción directa de `Trilateration`. El verbo asociado al uso de esta técnica sería entonces `trilaterar`.

Comment: trilateracionar, o trilaterar ? 

Veo que en ingles el verbo es "trilaterate" y no "trilaterationate"

Comment: Gracias. `trilaterar`, al igual que es "triangular" de "triangulación". Corrijo la respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

The RAE is not a perfect repository of all the words in the Spanish, it will mostly fail in recent terms or the ones in the scientific area as they are mostly proper names than actual terms.

Trilateración should be a correct translation until a better word is chosen.

Comment: So, also can I use the word as a verb, like "Trilaterar"? thanks for your answer Mike.

Comment: I would use that for the English "Trilaterate", maybe a translator (b.s. degree in translation)  could provide a better answer.

Comment: @Mike - Glad to see you typing more carefully, thank you!  Next step: provide some documentation when possible. // I do some freelance translating and when I guess at a word I google it to see if some well written texts use it.  In this case, when I did that, I saw several convincing examples of the use of *trilaterar* as a verb.